# click mouse with CoreGraphics, weirdly doesn't unclick

Tags: macos, core-graphics

The code below clicks the mouse, but (I think) doesn't unclick the mouse. I have to manually click the correct mouse button, then click again, and then it gets "unstuck".

And the two commented lines in the main function, for middle clicking or double-clicking, don't work either.

One-liner that reproduces issue:

```
echo '
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


void clickMouse(CGEventType mouseDown, CGEventType mouseUp, CGMouseButton mouseButton, UInt32 clickCount, CGEventFlags modifiers) {

  // current mouse position
  CGPoint mousePosition = CGEventGetLocation(CGEventCreate(NULL));

  // because?
  CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
  CGEventRef eventDown = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(source, mouseDown, mousePosition, mouseButton);
  CGEventRef eventUp   = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(source, mouseUp,   mousePosition, mouseButton);

  // necessary?
  CGEventSetType(eventDown, mouseDown);
  CGEventSetType(eventUp,   mouseUp);

  CGEventSetFlags(eventDown, modifiers);

  CGEventSetIntegerValueField(eventDown, kCGMouseEventClickState, clickCount);
  CGEventSetIntegerValueField(eventUp,   kCGMouseEventClickState, 0);

  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, eventDown);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, eventUp); // error here?

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  @autoreleasepool {
    clickMouse(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, kCGMouseButtonLeft, 1, 0);
  //clickMouse(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, kCGEventLeftMouseUp, kCGMouseButtonLeft, 2, 0);
  //clickMouse(kCGEventOtherMouseDown, kCGEventOtherMouseUp, kCGMouseButtonCenter, 1, 0);
  }

  return 0;
}

' > issue.m; gcc -ObjC -framework Cocoa  -o ./issue issue.m; ./issue
#
```

I am on:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
```

Related:

- [Performing a double click using CGEventCreateMouseEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483657/performing-a-double-click-using-cgeventcreatemouseevent)
- [CGEventPostToPSN() not working for mouse clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678239/cgeventposttopsn-not-working-for-mouse-clicking)

Comment: Why are you using different values for `kCGMouseEventClickState` for the down vs. the up event?

Comment: One of the linked answers recommended it. I had tried both different and the same.

Comment: @samboosalis  : try using a `modifiers=kCGEventFlagMaskShift ` ... `CGEventSetFlags(eventDown, modifiers);` .. it work for me ..

Comment: @rahul_send89 I already have that line in the code. And there is an issue even without modifiers. Did you copy and paste the one-liner into your terminal, and it didn't get stuck?